# How to call DLL's virtual function from executable? C++ VS2019

Tags: c++, pointers, dll, architecture

I'm programming my own game editor and it consists of lots of DLLs. Some DLLs uses other DLLs to derive some classes. The problem is whenever I call a virtual function (pure or not, result is same) with base class' pointer, application crashes. To visualize:

```
//DLL1.h in DLL1
class Base{
    static Base* SELF; //I use this to access functions
    void DoSometing(); //Defined in DLL1.cpp 
    virtual void VirtualSomething();
};

//DLL2.h in DLL2
class Derived : public Base{
    virtual void VirtualSomething(); //Defined in DLL2.cpp
};

//main.cpp in APP.exe
void main(){
     Base::SELF = new Derived;
     Base::SELF->DoSomething(); //Works fine
     Base::SELF->VirtualSomething(); //Crashes
}
```

Note: I have to use the Base::SELF pointer because I want to change it with another DLL later. It seems pretty awkward to create a Derived pointer and set it as Base::SELF here but it's more complicated than that, I'm creating this pointers in another DLL and pass them to application. I just wanted to give you the idea.

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with it, again a VS Debugger issue. Deleting some functions worked!